# How to remove packages during a build process (Unity 2020.3.x)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-cloud-build

I need to remove all firebase related packages depending on defines (preprocessor directives) during Unity Cloud Build process.

I created a class that implements `IPreprocessBuildWithReport` interface (to do my things in PreBuild stage) and runs removing script.
I tried two different approaches:

1. `UnityEditor.PackageManager.Client` class provides API to remove package proprely, but here is a problem that the class can't remove multiple packages in Unity Clound Build if Unity version is below 2021.3.x (this is my case and upgrade isn't an option), it just stops to remove after one or few pakages, locally works fine though.
2. edited manifest.json (in Packages folder) + AndroidManifest.xml, also removed all firebase related files directly through `System.IO.Directory` and `System.IO.File` in such Directories as:

- Assets/GeneratedLocalRepo/Firebase
- Library/PackageCache
- Assets/Plugins/Android

And finally `UnityEditor.CoreModule.AssetDatabase.Refresh()`.

In this case Unity Cloud Build finishes its job, but the build file crashes on a device.

Result i need to get is build file that has no firebase files in it and android manifest w/o any firebaseish records